# jQuery - how to set attr for 'this'..?

Tags: jquery

I was trying to iterate through a collection of objects and was trying to set an attribute for each of the object.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#clickButton').click(function() 
    {
        var hiddenVal = $('#hdnVal').val();

        $('*').find('*[tabindex]').each(function(index) 
        {
            //this.setAttribute('tabindex', hiddenVal + this.getAttribute('tabindex'));
            $(this).attr('tabindex', 'test');
        });
    });
});
```

I could not set the attribute with `$(this).attr('', '');` but the JavaScript way works fine. How can I do it in jQuery?

Comment: @Tim: good work on the code prettification :-)

Answer (score 2):

Setting a string to `tabIndex` will not work, it must be an integer.

```
$(this).attr('tabindex', 'test'); 
alert($(this).attr('tabindex')); 
// ^ alerts 0 in IE for me, indicating the default is restored
```

Try a number:

```
$(this).attr('tabindex', 1);
alert($(this).attr('tabindex')); 
// ^ alerts 1
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to get a hidden value set in hiddenVal and prefix the current value with the existing one. When i checked in firebug, the value won't change.. is that because the values are considered as text?

Comment: @Amit: Possibly.  Try casting the result to a number, eg `$(this).attr('tabindex', +(hiddenVal + $(this).attr('tabindex')));`

Comment: Hey there were so many cross browser issues.. i did it with plain javascript.. anyway Thanks Andy for suggestions..